# How to express the idea "up to a certain age" in poem

Tags: word-choice

I am not a native speaker, but I am writing a poem, where on a certain line the main character expresses the idea that he wants to reach an age of at least 90 and a couple of years more (not specified how many exactly). I used dictionaries and Internet but cannot find a clear answer. I am thinking of the following line: "It's ninety plus to which I strive".  I want to use the word "strive" because of the rhyme. Rythm and metre are also important for me. Some fitting alternatives for "to which" might be: "for which", "whereto", "wherefore". Which of these four is correct (or the best)?

Comment: *To which* is fine. Also consider *the nineties* instead of *ninety plus*.

Comment: If it is *It's ninety two unto which I strive*, it will be more rhythmic. Several *"t"* sounds!

Comment: 'for four-score ten and more i strive'

Comment: Just as an aside - ["wherefore" means "why"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wherefore?s=t); it has nothing to do with location or target.

Comment: It's ninety years I hope to thrive.

Comment: @Spagirl: I love your sentence. It's a beauty. Rhime, rythm and metre all fit in. I learned the word score for the first time when I read the magnificent speech of Martin Luther King, which he began in the same way as Abraham Lincoln in the Gettysburg Address.

Comment: @mahmud koya: the unto which is an anapestic foot amidst all iambic feet. Possible but it would be the only one in the whole poem giving it to much emphasis, I think. But thank you for your comment,

Comment: @Spratty: Thank you for the aside. I thought so already, but I thought of it because of to strive for.

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you. I noticed that apparently no one likes the plus. It is also good to know that my first idea of "to which" is just OK.

Comment: @Yosef Thank you. Your sentence will fit in pefectly as well considering the rhime, rhytm and metre, but it does not express it is more than  ninety years.

Answer (score 1):

To reach ninety-some is what I strive

Comment: This one fits very well with rhyme, rithm and metre and with the kind of wording in the poem. I like it, thank you very much.